# Variable not changing after its modified in C++

Tags: c++, variables

I am trying to run `balN` with the variable `N` changing as I change it in the program but `balN` is only running it with the value that was assigned with `N` at the very beginning. How can I make it so `balN` will change as the value of `N` changes? I am new to programming so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
const double Monintrate = 0.09 / 12.0;
const double Totnum = 36.0;
const double Payment = 165.25;

int main ()
{
  double N = 1.0;
  double balN = Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;

  cout << fixed;
  cout << setprecision(2) << "Monthly Payment: $" <<  Payment << endl;
  cout << "Annual Interest rate: 9%" << endl;
  cout << "Total Number of Payments: " << Totnum << endl << endl;

  cout << "Balance after Payment:" << endl;
  cout << "1: $" << balN << endl;
  N++;
  cout << "2: $" << balN << endl;
  N++;
  cout << "3: $" << balN << endl;
}
```

Comment: That is because you never assign any other values to `balN`. You are only modifying `N`.

Comment: You'll have to repeat the calculation. You could do something like `for (int i = 1; 1 <= 3; ++i) {double balN = calculate(i); cout << ...;}` with `calculate` taking a `double`, and then get rid of the mentions of `balN` and `N` earlier.

Comment: You've written a one-time variable assignment expression within the main() function when you probably meant to define a distinct function outside of it, which you could then use multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in your program, you only modified the value of `N`, not `balN`, you need to call

```
balN = Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;
```

every time you modified `N`.

```
cout << "1: $" << balN << endl;
N++;
balN = Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;
cout << "2: $" << balN << endl;
N++;
balN = Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;
cout << "3: $" << balN << endl;
```

Comment: Of course, it would be better to put the calculation in a function and call that instead of copying.

Comment: @Hulk Yes, that would be better if the calculation is a little complicated like this one.

Answer (score 2):

You never reassign `balN` with the new values depending on `N`.

You should reassign it every time you change `N`:

```
cout << "1: $" << balN << endl;
N++;
balN = Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;
cout << "2: $" << balN << endl;
N++;
balN = Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;
cout << "3: $" << balN << endl;
```

Maybe a loop here can be a solution to avoid code repetition:

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ )
{
    balN = Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;
    cout << i << ": $" << balN << endl;
    N++;
}
```

Or Use a function to do that:

```
double calcBalN( double N )
{
    return Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;
}

int main ()
{
    // ...
    cout << "1: $" << calcBalN( N ) << endl;
    N++;
    cout << "2: $" << calcBalN( N ) << endl;
    N++;
    cout << "3: $" << calcBalN( N ) << endl;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double balN = Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;
```

The expression at the right side of the assignment will be evaluated and the result will be store in `balN`.
The value of `balN` won't be modified if you don't reassign a new value to it, even if the value of `N` is modified.

What you could do is define your calculation in a function and update `balN` with it :

```
double process(double N) {
    const double Monintrate = 0.09 / 12.0;
    const double Totnum = 36.0;
    const double Payment = 165.25;
    return Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;;
}

int main ()
{
    double N = 1.0;
    double balN = process(N);

    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(2) << "Monthly Payment: $" <<  Payment << endl;
    cout << "Annual Interest rate: 9%" << endl;
    cout << "Total Number of Payments: " << Totnum << endl << endl;

    cout << "Balance after Payment:" << endl;
    cout << "1: $" << balN << endl;
    N++;
    balN = process(N);
    cout << "2: $" << balN << endl;
    N++;
    balN = process(N);
    cout << "3: $" << balN << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `balN` a function. C language does not support reactive programming otherwise you could have benefitted with your code. Following code will help.

```
const double Monintrate = 0.09 / 12.0;
const double Totnum = 36.0;
const double Payment = 165.25;

double balN (double N)·
{
double bal = Payment * (1 - pow(1 + Monintrate, N - Totnum))/Monintrate;
return bal;·
}
int main ()
{
double N = 1.0;

cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2) << "Monthly Payment: $" <<  Payment << endl;
cout << "Annual Interest rate: 9%" << endl;
cout << "Total Number of Payments: " << Totnum << endl << endl;

cout << "Balance after Payment:" << endl;
cout << "1: $" << balN() << endl;
N++;
cout << "2: $" << balN() << endl;
N++;
cout << "3: $" << balN() << endl;
}
```